Hashicorp vault-agent-init is failing with auth.handler: error authenticating. Unable to start container (minikube)
I am unable to start my app pods in minikube. The reason being my vault-agent-init container is having errors. I have configured the hashicorp vault agent in my minikube following the official doc and I was successfully able to store the secrets. But when I do the pod deployment, the pod is not starting.
amarnathjayakrishnan@Amarnaths-MacBook-Pro mock-layer % kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE                  NAME                                        READY   STATUS     RESTARTS      AGE
mock-svc   mock-svc-6d66794d7c-7nsft   0/2     Init:0/1   0             13m
mock-svc   otel-collector-76c69579f8-7ttln             1/1     Running    0             28m
vault                      vault-0                                     1/1     Running    0             31m
vault                      vault-agent-injector-95c7b5566-4t4kf        1/1     Running    0             31m



amarnathjayakrishnan@Amarnaths-MacBook-Pro mock-layer % kubectl logs mock-svc-6d66794d7c-7nsft -c vault-agent-init -n mock-svc
==> Vault Agent started! Log data will stream in below:

2024-04-19T01:14:14.150Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: creating file sink
2024-04-19T01:14:14.150Z [INFO]  agent.sink.file: file sink configured: path=/home/vault/.vault-token mode=-rw-r-----
==> Vault Agent configuration:

           Api Address 1: http://bufconn
                     Cgo: disabled
               Log Level: info
                 Version: Vault v1.16.1, built 2024-04-03T12:35:53Z
             Version Sha: 6b5986790d7748100de77f7f127119c4a0f78946

2024-04-19T01:14:14.151Z [INFO]  agent.exec.server: starting exec server
2024-04-19T01:14:14.151Z [INFO]  agent.exec.server: no env templates or exec config, exiting
2024-04-19T01:14:14.151Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: starting auth handler
2024-04-19T01:14:14.151Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2024-04-19T01:14:14.151Z [INFO]  agent.template.server: starting template server
2024-04-19T01:14:14.151Z [INFO]  agent: (runner) creating new runner (dry: false, once: false)
2024-04-19T01:14:14.151Z [INFO]  agent.sink.server: starting sink server
2024-04-19T01:14:14.152Z [INFO]  agent: (runner) creating watcher
2024-04-19T01:14:14.156Z [ERROR] agent.auth.handler: error authenticating: error="Put \"http://vault-server.bitnami-vault:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login\": dial tcp: lookup vault-server.bitnami-vault on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host" backoff=860ms
2024-04-19T01:14:15.020Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2024-04-19T01:14:15.028Z [ERROR] agent.auth.handler: error authenticating: error="Put \"http://vault-server.bitnami-vault:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login\": dial tcp: lookup vault-server.bitnami-vault on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host" backoff=860ms
2024-04-19T01:14:16.425Z [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
2024-04-19T01:14:16.438Z [ERROR] agent.auth.handler: error authenticating: error="Put \"http://vault-server.bitnami-vault:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login\": dial tcp: lookup vault-server.bitnami-vault on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host" backoff=1.39s

Relevant parts from my Values.yaml:
podAnnotations:
  prometheus.io/path: /actuator/prometheus
  prometheus.io/port: "8080"
  prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
  vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
  vault.hashicorp.com/agent-init-first: "true"
  vault.hashicorp.com/service: "http://vault-server.bitnami-vault:8200"
  vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'mock-svc'
  vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-database-config.json: 'abc/data/mock-svc/config'
  vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-database-config.json: |
    {{- with secret "abc/data/mock-svc/config" -}}
    export DB_USER="{{ .Data.data.mock_postgresdb_username }}"
    export DB_PASSWORD="{{ .Data.data.postgresdb_password }}"
    export DB_HOST="{{ .Data.data.postgresdb_hostname }}"
    export DB_PORT="{{ .Data.data.postgresdb_port }}"
    export DB_NAME="{{ .Data.data.postgresdb_dbname }}"
    export DB_SSL="{{ .Data.data.postgresdb_ssl }}"
    {{- end }}

